# Why am I getting all kinds of errors in React TypeScript imports?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm-package

`Module '"react"' has no exported member 'useEffect'` and a lot more.

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
  ]
}
```

[`home.tsx` import region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29iqQ.png)

[project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXY7q.png)

Here I tried reinstalling react-router-dom:

[npm install react-router-dom error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlzSa.png)

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.1",
    "@mantine/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@mantine/hooks": "^7.4.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.19",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.16",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^6.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.18.4",
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.5.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/bonjour": "^3.5.13",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.45",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.60",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.47",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.14",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.5.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "hammer": "^0.0.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "mdb-react-ui-kit": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.9",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.18.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-tinder-card": "^1.6.4",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.29"
  }
}
```

npm install:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.3.3
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   typescript@"^5.3.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"^5.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-07T22_00_27_549Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

and now I'm getting:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\lucru IS\react\frontend\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\ipaddr.js\lib\ipaddr.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry  
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:415:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:665:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1034:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\lucru IS\react\frontend\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:8:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\lucru IS\\react\\frontend\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\node_modules\\ipaddr.js\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'ipaddr.js'
}

Node.js v20.8.0
```

as well.

The problem began when I installed express and dotenv from Spotify web API documentation but after I got a lot of Webpack errors, did some `npm audit fix --force`, I didn't think it could do this kind of damage
I tried deleting `node_modules` and doing an `npm install` as well as check on all kinds of websites.

Comment: _Read the error message_ when you `npm install`, it explains which packages you've installed that are mutually incompatible. You should pretty much never run `npm audit fix --force` as that applies major version changes.

Comment: Try this: move `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` to a different location outside of your project directory, then simply run `npm install`.  This will cause NPM to reinstall everything as defined in your `package.json` dependencies and devDependencies.  Hopefully all goes without error.  As @jonrsharpe says: you pretty much should NEVER run `--force` unless you really, really, really, really know what you are doing.  I don't think I have ever used `--force` myself.

Comment: You shouldn't run `--force` unless you know what you're doing, and when you know what you're doing you know you shouldn't run it! It's a baffling misfeature to make that the first suggestion people most see in the command output.

Comment: Tried removing node_modules and package-lock.json and doing a cache clean aswell but i get the new npm install error

Comment: it looks like react-scripts@5.0.1 requires typescript version ^3.2.1 || ^4 but there is typescript ^5.3.3 in your dependencies. Try to downgrade typescript to ^4

Comment: this is what worked lastly but forgot to give an update, thank you all!